# Firebase gives "path not recognized" error for post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase to host my nodejs app and am using Cloud Functions.

Using the command `firebase serve --only functions,hosting` I am deploying my app.

I have a form with `action="/putNPK"`  and works perfectly when run from node.

But when I serve it through firebase , I am getting this error when I submit the form.

```
{"error":{"code":404,"status":"NOT_FOUND","message":"/putNPK is not a recognized path.","errors":["/putNPK is not a recognized path."]}}
```

How to fix this?

**firebase.json looks like this :-**

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "trailingSlash": true
  }
}
```

This is my folder structure :-

[image]

> Contents of index.js :-

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin") ; 
const express = require("express") ; 
const app = require("express")() ; 
const bodyparser = require("body-parser") ; 
const functions = require("firebase-functions") ;
const request_controller = require("./requests_controller") ; 



app.use(express.static('../public/assets/')) ; 
app.use(express.static('../public/')) ;

request_controller(app) ; 

app.use((req ,res , next)=>{
    res.status(404).redirect('404.html') ; 
})

app.listen(8000) ; 

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app) ;
```

> COntents of requests_controller file (module imported in index.js) :-

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin") ; 
const bodyparser = require("body-parser") ; 
const app = require("express")() ; 
const urlencodedParser =bodyparser.urlencoded({extended : true}) ;
const posthandler = require("posthandler") ;
const gethandler = require("gethandler") ;


var serviceAccount = require("C:/Users/Natesh/Documents/raita-mitra-2018-firebase-adminsdk (acnt nateshmbhat1).json");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://raita-mitra-2018.firebaseio.com"
});



//Validates POST request body and checks if the request contains all the keys('strings') in the array sent as keys argument
function validatePostBody(req , res , keys ){
    for(i in keys){
        if(!(keys[i] in req.body))
        {
            console.log("invalid post request returning ! ") ; 
            return false ; 
        }
    }
    return true ; 
}



module.exports = function Handle_requests(app)
{
    console.log('Request Handler started ! ') ;

    app.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') ; 
    })

    app.get('/home' , (req , res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') ; 
    })


    app.post('/putNPK', urlencodedParser ,(req , res)=>{
        if(!validatePostBody(req , res , ['fertilizer' ,'crop' , 'nitrogen' , 'phone' , 'phosphorus' , 'potassium'])) return ;  

        ref = admin.database().ref('/users/' + req.body.phone) ; 
        ref.set(req.body) ;
        console.log("Added to firebase database") ;
        res.status(200).redirect('/') ;

        admin.messaging().sendToTopic('global' , {
            notification : {
                title : 'Farmer Project' ,
                body : 'notification body'
            } , 
            data : {
                nitrogen : req.body.nitrogen
            }
        })

    } )

}
```

Comment: What's your rewrite rule to get Hosting to proxy your request to Cloud Functions?

Comment: I have posted the contents of my firebase.json . PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Could you show your cloud functions index.js?

Comment: It looks like `/putNPK` is a node.js specific route. You would likely need to change the `action='/putNPK'` to the firebase endpoint you are trying to save to.

Comment: If thats the case how come get requests to web pages work fine and not POST requests ? And its not at all a good idea to refer to the firebase link directly .

Comment: Maybe try to add to the rewrites `{"source": "/putNPK", "function": "app"}` in the array of rewrites.

Comment: This may have also been addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461082/how-to-configure-rewrite-rules-inside-firebase-hosting-to-route-certain-requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found a simple fix for this** :-

> - "/path" (with a slash before 'path') works in **nodejs** but **not in firebase**.
> - "path" (without the SLASH) works both in nodejs and firebase.

Instead of `action ="/postpath"`  , it should be  `action="postpath"` . This ensures that the get and post request go to the express router in a relative path manner which firebase forwards to the concerned function .

If the path is not relative , for example if ur running a localserver , then `action="/postpath"` resolves to `localhost:8000/postpath` which works fine in nodejs but in firebase it doesn't work since firebase's function has its own URL over the firebase hosting server .

Therefore `localhost:8000/postpath` won't even get passed to our express app function handler.

But when `action="postpath"` is used , it resolves this as **`http://localhost:5001/<project-id>/us-central1/app/postpath`**  and now works perfectly.

---

#### **EDIT 1:-**

Also if one or more of your static files are not getting served , (you are getting 404 error) , it might be because you have included your `<script src="/path">` with a slash at the beginning of the source .

Remove the `/` and it works flawlessly.