# I can't access on express route on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Now I created a file by node server like

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const express = require("express")

/* Express */
const app = express()
app.get("/test", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase!")
})

const api1 = functions.https.onRequest(app)


module.exports = {
  api1
}
```

firebase.json

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

and I have deployed it to firebase hosting and try tried access it on firebase hosting the index.html show up to me but when I require the `/test` it's return as 404.html page ! what's I'm missing ?

> after updated firebase.json and added rewrites to

```
{
  "hosting": 
  {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
          "source": "/test",
          "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the message is different now
[image]

---

### The answer

---

I must to structured my project files to 
-project (folder)
---functions (folder)(contains on all nodejs files)
---public (filder)

Comment: Can you include your firebase.json file please? Did you forget to set the rewrite?

Comment: @JeremyW thanks for your interesting ,I have added a firebase.json file

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `rewrites` section to your firebase.json file. That tells the Firebase servers how to route any requests that come in... and right now, you aren't telling it anything.

```
"hosting": {
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "**",
            "function": "api1"
        }
    ]
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44475330/8026947) isn't actually an answer to your question, but it demonstrates the proper way to set up rewrites with cloud function express apps.

Comment: and how about if I have several routes like 

const users= require('./routes/users');
const books= require('./routes/books');
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/books', books);

Comment: after I added the rewrites the message became different "404. That’s an error.
The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo You mean that after you've added the rewrites, and you visit `/test?` or `/`? then you get the 404? Any other route other than `/test` will 404 because it isn't configured in your Express instance. If you had other routes then you'd just have to include them in your express setup, just like any other node.js project. The rewrite sends ALL requests (*the double astrisk*) to your express app at the moment.

Comment: in this moment I only have just one route`/test` that happened when call root `/` the index.html appear to men but when call `/test' the message that I added in top appear to me **404. That’s an error. The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know**

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo Hmmm, well that doesn't make any sense to me - with your rewrites section, `/test` SHOULD be showing your Hello message.

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo I see your update - check your "function" value in your rewrite rule. You have `app` whereas you need `api1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190454/discussion-between-jeremyw-and-mahmoud-niypoo).

Comment: Finally i found what was wrong , I must sort my files as project/functions/nodejs files nad project/public/assets files

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo Thanks for coming back and letting me know - I've been scratching my head the whole afternoon about what it was.